# Proving this integral operator is bounded - correct attempt?

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

I think I have managed to prove the claim below and would appreciate any feedback.

> Let $K \in C([0,1]^2)$. Then the integral operator $T : \big(C([0,1]),
>  ||\cdot||_{L^2}\big) \to \big(C([0,1]), ||\cdot||_\infty\big)$ given
> by:
>
> $$Tf(x)=\int_0^1 K(x,y)f(y)dy$$
>
> is bounded.

Here is my (hopefully correct) proof:

$$ ||Tf||_\infty=\sup_{x \in X} \bigg|\int_0^1 K(x,y)f(y)dy\bigg |\leq \sup_{x \in X} \bigg|c\int_0^1 f(y)\cdot 1dy\bigg | \leq \sup_{x \in X} \bigg|c||f||_{L^2}||1||_{L^2}\bigg | =c||f||_{L^2}$$

where the first inequality follows since $K$ is continuous and so obtains a maximum value $c$, and the second inequality follows from Cauchy-Schwartz.

In case this is incorrect - where am I mistaken and what could I do instead in order to prove this?

Comment: There should be $|f(y)|$ after the first occurence of $\le$ and $\sup_x$ is redundant in the last two expressions. The correct spelling is Schwarz.

Comment: The problem here is that you applied Cauchy-Scwarz too soon. I agree with Ryszard, you should have $|f(y)|$ within the integral. I recommend that you use triangle inequality fr integrals and bring in the absolute value  into the integrand. Then you can bound said integral by maximizing the absolute value of the kernel and then finally apply Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct chain of inequalities.

$$ ||Tf||_\infty=\sup_{x \in X} \bigg|\int_0^1 K(x,y)f(y)dy\bigg |\leq\sup_{x \in X} \int_0^1 \bigg|K(x,y)f(y)\bigg|dy\leq \sup_{x \in X}c \int_0^1 \bigg|f(y)\bigg|\cdot 1dy \leq \sup_{x \in X} c||f||_{L^2}||1||_{L^2}=c||f||_{L^2}$$